# Torrent to direct-link converter

Tags: webapp-rec

Which are the websites which help to ***direct download*** BitTorrent files?

One such service is [Torrific](http://torrific.com):

> What torrific does is, when we give the
>   url of a **.torrent** file, it will
>   download the file on its server and
>   give us the  **direct link** for the
>   downloaded file.

*Since Torrific has a bandwidth limit of 10GB per day I am looking for other free alternatives.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Fetch.io](http://fetch.io)

Lets you stream media on the site, pretty new.

Answer (score 1):

[Put.io](http://put.io/) is one such service, as is [Leechpack](http://www.leechpack.com/). ImageShack used to offer the same, but they have shut down that service.

Comment: they are not free :(

Comment: Works great though. I hope they don't get mired in copyrights issues.

Answer (score 0):

[Instant-Torrents](http://instant-torrents.com/). This one doesn't offer any free bandwidth.

[zbigz](http://zbigz.com/). Offers free bandwidth, but limits download speeds. You can pay to become premium.